# how to transfer crud properties of a user of a certain record to another

Tags: apex, trigger, soql, userrecordaccess, record-access-level

How may i transfer CRUD properties of a record assigned to the owner of that record   to another user in apex? UserRecordAccess could be used to find the properties but how to do it for multiple records which may have different owners.

Comment: so you want a user with permissions to, say Update a record R give Update permissions to a different user? CRUD is controlled by permission sets/profiles. If both have Read visibility on object, then record visibility is controlled by sharing rules

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about sharing, you can read [this part of the developer guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_bulk_sharing_creating_with_apex.htm).

If they have already the same permission sets/profile, this is the way.